# Why are my IK bones rotating my DEF bones like so?

Tags: rigging, rigify, inverse-kinematics

Any ideas as to why the IK bones of my rig are twisting the arm like so? This is of course using rigify.

[image: IK Bones twisting deformations.]

This doesn't occur with FK bones posed to the same position, it just appears to be happening with Inverse Kinematics.

[image: FK Bones do NOT twist the deformations.]

I've attempted to regenerate the rig multiple times--- I tested multiple bone roll orientations as well as creating a more exaggerated elbow bend, to no avail. I've went through all the IK constraints and haven't found anything obviously wrong there. It occurs on both left and right arms.

This isn't exclusive to this project either, as I had the same issue before with a previous character, I couldn't find a solution there either.

[Blend file containing just the generated rig and the metarig](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtM_pc3Q-xDugSN0zfnRcaeN1QQY?e=s6V3mt)

In the file I've hidden non pertinent deformation bones to make seeing the exact twisting problem more clear. Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This might help: https://youtu.be/gq7K1mX4pRI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, my bad, I forgot to come back and close the question.

I solved it, and it turns out I had it right when I was attempting to create an elbow bend, I just wasn't bending it enough.

For people who might have this issue in the future, the easiest way to go about fixing it is to:

Generate your rig as normal
Parent the mesh to the rig
Pose your arms via FK to pull the elbow back, by a considerable degree too.
Duplicate the armature modifier on the mesh, apply one of them
Copy the transforms you made on the rig onto the metarig
Regenerate the rig, re weight your mesh.